# jacoco offline instrumentation original class path

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, pom.xml, jacoco

According to http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html, when doing offline instrumentation, I need to provide the original class files to generate the report.  Exactly how do I do that with Maven?  I know the original class file is saved under generated-classes folder so right now I'm just copying the generated-classes folder over the classes folder when running generating the report but is there a way to specify the original class file path within the POM file?  I couldn't find any examples anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jacoco-maven-plugin provides [instrument](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/instrument-mojo.html) that comes in a pair with [restore-instrumented-classes](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/restore-instrumented-classes-mojo.html). And there is an example of usage in JaCoCo documentation -  http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom-offline.xml